# Typescript: using embedded objects for constants

Tags: typescript

In JavaScript I use constants like this:

```
module.exports = {
    ACTIONS: {
        ACTION1: "Action",
        ACTION2: ...
    }
    TEST: "test",
    ...
};
```

And next use it like this:

```
var Constants = requre(../utils/constants.js);
console.log(Constants.ACTIONS.ACTION1); //Action
console,log(Constants.TEST); //test
```

Is there a way to use a similar structure in the Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing in TypeScript:

```
// utils/constants.ts
export = {
    ACTIONS: {
        ACTION1: "Action"
    },
    TEST: "test"
};
```

Then in your other file:

```
import Constants = require("./../utils/constants");

console.log(Constants.ACTIONS.ACTION1); // Action
console.log(Constants.TEST);            // test
```

**ES6 Imports**

If you're using ES6 imports, then you can do:

```
export default {
    ACTIONS: {
        ACTION1: "Action"
    },
    TEST: "test"
};
```

Then:

```
import Constants from "./../utils/constants";
// use Constants here
```

Comment: @qweasd it's just a simple object so doing this is perfectly fine. It's less code to maintain. I updated the answer to show how to use ES6 imports in case you want to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way, using a method get, that will keep the properties readonly:

```
module Constants {
    export class Actions {
        public static get ACTION1(): string { return "ACTION1"; }
        public static get ACTION2(): string { return "ACTION2"; }
    }

    export class Test {
        public static get TEST1(): string { return "TEST1"; }
        public static get TEST2(): string { return "TEST2"; }
    }
}
```

And then call like below:

```
console.log(Actions.ACTION1); //Action
console.log(Test.TEST1); //Test
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use embedded values in this way, if `ACTIONS1` returned object?

Comment: @qweasd It's an static get method, you don't need a class instance to use static stuff :) and It's return a string, not an object, you can return anything you want.

Answer (score -2):

maybe something like.

```
module Constants{
    export enum Actions {
        ACTION1 = <any> 'Action1'

    }

    export enum Test {
        TEST1 = <any> 'Test1'

    }

    export const TEST = 'TEST';

}

class HelloWorld{
    public static main(){

        console.log(Constants.Actions.ACTION1);
        console.log(Constants.Test.TEST1);

        console.log(Constants.TEST);
    }
}
HelloWorld.main();
```

Console:

```
Action1
Test1
TEST
```